# How can I get all the elements in an array using .fetch?

Tags: arrays, ruby, date

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails and I have data in an array which is a Date data type. I'm trying to have a date comparison with each of the dates in the array so I used `.fetch` to retrieve one of the dates to test it out with `Date.today` and it worked. But is there a way for fetch to iterate over each date in the array?

For example:

```
act = [Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Tue, 30 Oct 2018, Sun, 01 Jul 2018]
```

`act.fetch(0)` is `Tue, 30 Oct 2018` and that is a Date data type.

Also, if I don't call fetch and try to do a block statement to iterate, I get an error that states:

> no implicit conversion of Date into Array

EDIT 1: When I tried to iterate using the Array#each like this:

```
     2.4.0 :001 > cted = Activity.pluck(:start_date).each do |acts|
2.4.0 :002 >           if Date.today >= acts
2.4.0 :003?>             Date.today
2.4.0 :004?>           elsif acts > Date.today
2.4.0 :005?>             acts
2.4.0 :006?>           end
2.4.0 :007?>       end
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "activities"."start_date" FROM "activities"
 => [Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 17 Jun 2018, Sun, 15 Apr 2018, Tue, 26 Jun 2018]
```

It returns the array when I tried to use it.

```
def closer_to_end_date
  Activity.pluck(:start_date).each do |acts|
    if Date.today >= acts
      Date.today
    elsif acts > Date.today
      acts
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `act` is an array. There are plenty ways to iterate through an array in Ruby, but the recommended and if you don't need anything "extra" is using [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

Comment: When I use the `Array#each` I get a `expected Numeric` error. My code is               
    `def event_days
    Activity.pluck(:end_date).each do |endz|
      (endz - closer_to_end_date).to_i
    end
  end`

Comment: It seems to be a difference in the data types you're comparing. What's the value of `closer_to_end_date`? try `(endz - closer_to_end_date.to_date).to_i`.

Comment: I get this error `undefined method `to_date' for #<Array:0x007fd11a803ca0> Did you mean? to_a` also this is that method its subtracting from ```def closer_to_end_date
    Activity.pluck(:start_date).each do |acts|
      if Date.today >= acts
        Date.today
      elsif acts > Date.today
        acts
      end
    end
  end```

Answer (score 2):

`closer_to_end_date` returns an Enumerator, because is what the call of `each` in an array returns, so, actually the subtraction `endz - closer_to_end_date` is being applied in a date and an array object.

If you wanna store the value after each comparison in `closer_to_end_date` you could try using `map`, it'll store each value you return within the iteration, resulting in a new array.

Try tweaking a bit your code like:

```
def closer_to_end_date
  Activity.pluck(:start_date).map do |acts|
    if Date.today >= acts
      Date.today.to_date
    elsif acts > Date.today
      acts
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that code in the rail console and it returns a 'nil' array.   IE: 
```2.4.0 :004 > start = Activity.pluck(:start_date).map do |acts|
2.4.0 :005 >     puts acts
2.4.0 :006?>   end
   (1.1ms)  SELECT "activities"."start_date" FROM "activities"
2018-06-17
2018-06-17
2018-06-17
2018-06-17
2018-06-17
2018-06-17
2018-04-15
2018-06-26
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] ```

Comment: That's because you're not storing nothing within the map block. Each value is nil because of the result of using puts, that's always nil

Comment: I'm not understanding how I can store something in the block (Like fetch) to return the date. Could you send me an example please?

Comment: The code in the answer is an example. It should store the value of `Date.today.to_date` or `acts` depending on what they return, assuming the can have any value, even nil. But in the code you provided, it stores the result of each `puts acts`, knowing that puts always returns nil, nil is what the map will store. I must go in my steps and the _you're not storing nothing _ was wrong, you're storing nil. Just try the code I provided in the answer.